# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 OS updates through the Software application not completed

Tags: gnome, updates, notification

The Software application sends a notification indicating that OS updates are available. When I click the install button it starts installing the updates but then gets stuck at about 10% of the process.

Here's a screenshot of the issue :

[image: Here's a screenshot of the issue].

No other tasks are affected and I can continue to work with no problems, and other updates install without any issues.
When I run apt-get update it works normally, but the notification continues to appear.

How can I install the updates the alert mentions? or is it an issue with the OS update notification?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting, the alerts should be gone.

Comment: This worked. after rebooting the notification appeared again, but this time when I clicked install the updates completed.